# Large data in a cell of DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

i want to display a large data in a cell of DataGridView as multiplelines to avoid the horizontalscroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the DefaultCellStyle's WrapMode:

```
Me.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
```

For further information have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx)